# Example of a communtative ring with two operations where the identity elements are not distinct?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

I was introduced to the definition of a field today, as a communtative ring with two operations, like $\Bbb{R} = \langle R, +, -, \cdot, ^{-1} \rangle$ and all the usual axioms; commutativity,  associativity, identity & inverse elements, but there was a remark in the axioms that said the identity element of addition must be distinct from then identity element of multiplication, $ 0 \neq 1$. Is there a reason why this must be, and is there an example of a ring where this is not the case?

Comment: If $0 = 1$ in a ring $R$, then $0 = 0x = 1x = x$ for all $x\in R$; that is, $R = 0$.

Comment: Suppose that $1=0$.  Then $x=1\cdot x = 0\cdot x = (0+0)\cdot x = 0x + 0x = 1x+1x=x+x$ implying that $x=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [zero ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring), a ring containing only one element, necessarily has $0 = 1$, since this ring satisfies all the ring axioms (except $0 \neq 1$), but only has one element.  The zero ring is a bit pathological, so rather than writing "Let $R$ be any ring other than the zero ring", we exclude the zero ring via the "$0 \neq 1$" condition.

There is also a notion "[field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element)".  Note that even if one works in a setting where the field with one element makes sense, this object is not a field, for the same axiomatic reason as is used to exclude the zero ring.

Answer (score 1):

The identity element under addition is denoted by $0$. It has the property that $0*a = 0 = a*0$ for all $a\in R$.

The identity element under multiplication is denoted $1$. It has the property that $1*a = a = a*1$ for all $a \in R$.

If $0 = 1$, then for all $a \in R$,

$$ 0 = 0*a = 1*a = a.$$

So $R = \{0\}$. We don't like to call this a field as it doesn't behave like one.

Answer (score 1):

If $0 = 1$, then for any $x$ in the ring:
$$x = x.1 = x.0 = 0$$
and therefore there is only one element in the ring.